# Passing Data to VNCoreMLRequest

Tags: ios, swift, coreml

I have a `VNCoreMLRequest` setup to run my model:

```swift
lazy var classificationRequest: VNCoreMLRequest = {
        do {
            let model = try VNCoreMLModel(for: Test().model)
            
            let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model, completionHandler: { [weak self] request, error in
                self?.processClassifications(for: request, error: error, label: passedlabel) //passedlabel doesn't exist, can't find how to pass it to this object
            })
            request.imageCropAndScaleOption = .centerCrop
            return request
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to load Vision ML model: \(error)")
        }
    }()
```

I am trying to pass a parameter `label: UILabel` to this request so that it can pass it on to `processClassifications`, so when processing the results I know which label to output them to. This will allow me to run multiple requests at the same time and be able to process all of the outputs to different labels.

Right now `AnalyseImage` passes `label` to -> `updateClassifications(label)`, but `updateClassifications` runs `handler.perform([self.classificationRequest])` and I can't figure out how to pass the label along to this  `VNCoreMLRequest`.

```swift
    @IBAction func AnalyseImage(_ sender: Any) {
        updateClassifications(for: (LastImage), label: OutputLabel)
    }
    func updateClassifications(for image: UIImage, label: UILabel) {
        label.text = "Classifying..."
        let orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation(rawValue: UInt32(image.imageOrientation.rawValue))!
        guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: image) else { fatalError("Unable to create \(CIImage.self) from \(image).") }
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: ciImage, orientation: orientation)
            do {
                try handler.perform([self.classificationRequest]) //NEED TO PASS LABEL TO CLASSIFICATION REQUEST
            } catch {
                print("Failed to perform classification.\n\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
```

The VNCoreMLRequest calls `processClassifications`, and needs to be passed the `label` so that it can pass it to `processClassifications`. This will allow me to output results onto the label.

```swift
    func processClassifications(for request: VNRequest, error: Error?, label: UILabel) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let results = request.results else {
                self.OutputOne.text = "Unable to classify image.\n\(error!.localizedDescription)"
                return
            }
            //output results to label here
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see VNRequest having an identifier in API to get a specific request by label. What I did is to retain the optional VNRequests eg body, and hand in a builder design pattern. I think you can create a wrapper with general VNRequest and label to retain the VNRequest and results?